# How can I create an "unfilled frame" in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm sure this is something super-simple, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am trying to create a "widget" that consists of three lines of text, stacked vertically. This information should be placed inside a "frame" or "border" so it resembles a card. There will be a row of these cards that will scroll horizontally.

Believe it or not, the only part of this I cannot figure out is how to draw the border around the widget. I've tried .border, but that snugs the border right up against the text. I know I can add padding, but what I really need is a fixed-size card so each element in the scrolling list is identical.

I've come closest using this:

```
.frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.3, height: 200)
.background(Color.white)
.border(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(20)
```

...but the corners are all clipped. For reference, here's the complete code listing:

```
struct AccountTile: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Account Balance").font(.largeTitle)
                Text("Account Name").font(.headline)
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("There are ").font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text("6 ").font(.caption).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("unreconciled transactions.").font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.3, height: 200)
            .background(Color.white)
            .border(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
    }
}
```

...and here's what that code is producing:

[image: clipped image]

This is *almost* what I'm looking for - I just need the border to be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some padding and [overlay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269703-overlay) to create your border. Here is the code (:

```
struct AccountTile: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Account Balance").font(.largeTitle)
                Text("Account Name").font(.headline)
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("There are ").font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text("6 ").font(.caption).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("unreconciled transactions.").font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.3, height: 200)
                .background(Color.white)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the GeometryReader to make the frame a specific width in relation to the screen size; how would that fit in with your solution? Doesn't the padding just make the text views a little bigger without making them a fixed size?

Comment: Yes you can achieve the same result with your frame, I added the padding just to create some space between the border. I will update my answer.